# Opening browser when push notification is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I want to open the browser when the user taps a push notification.

In my app delegate I have:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {    
    var json = remoteNotif[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as! NSDictionary

    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let navC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainNav") as! NavViewController

    let data = json.objectForKey("data") as! NSDictionary
    let url = data.objectForKey("url") as! String
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: url)!)

    self.window?.rootViewController = navC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() 
}
```

When the user taps the push notification this gives me a black screen for 20 seconds, then the app opens, and then the browser opens.
How can I make the tap on the push notification open only the browser, or at least open faster than 20 seconds?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved ?

Comment: no... In the end a made a new UIViewController with a webView

Comment: ok thanks for sharing the alternate way . :) !

Comment: You should get response in the block then try. like this  let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     }
        }

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue although I am just opening an URL. The problem I was trying to open the URL (that's network task) without putting the code in a background thread. Just use this and it's opened right after the push notification is clicked:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "myURL")!)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't open another app directly - you can only use fast app switching.
The 20 seconds black screen sounds strange - is it consistent across multiple devices?

If so - you should really run instruments and see what functions take such a long time to work. It sounds like the loading before your app appears is very heavy for some reason.

If Instruments doesn't give you anything (And I'm pretty sure it will) you should look at what do you link the app agains - is it a gigantic list of frameworks?

As a quick hack in case loading the storyboard is the heavy part - You can try to do the openURL itself before loading the storyboard.

Make sure the shouldOpenURL method in the app delegate is very efficient and not doing any synchronous network tasks or something funky like that.

Comment: i will run instruments, but the app loads grate and fast with different pushes i get that opens the app itself (i didn't post the all os the code). only when i call UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: url)!) i get the black screen

Comment: You can press stop on Xcode a couple of seconds after you get the black screen and check your call stack on the debug navigator, maybe that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is connected with RunLoop when an app is bringing to Active state. So you just need to put your code in the end of current loop.

Below is demonstrated the **Swift 3.2** code for opening URL from a push notification when it was tapped by an user from iOS:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable : Any] {
        self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: remoteNotification, fetchCompletionHandler: {_ in })
    }
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .inactive ||
        UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active { //the app is bringing to an user
        if let urlString = ((userInfo["aps"] as? [String : Any])?["content"] as? [String: Any])?["link"] as? String, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
}
```

PS: based on Marcos Reboucas answer